# R convert list to character

Tags: r, list, character

I have a problem in converting a list to a given character pattern.

For example, I have a list in R:

```
tt <- list(c("e7", "9f", "b3", "e5", "ae", "b6", "e5", "ba", "84"))
```

And I want to get the character like this:

```
'%e7%9f%b3%e5%ae%b6%e5%ba%84'
```

How can I do? Thanks.

Comment: `paste("%", tt[[1]], sep="", collapse="")`.

Comment: @Arun - tiny variation - `paste0("%",unlist(tt),collapse="")`

Comment: @thelatemail I think that would put a `%` at the end as well.

Comment: @nograpes - nope, works for me.

Comment: I found that gsub()function is quite convenient too:)